# Record live video and audio using iOS, Android and desktop and save it using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, video

I am trying to record a video with audio (for desktop it will use web cam and headphone if any, for IOS and Andriod it will use phone camera and mic).
Tried to implement using (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) but when I tried the given demo its not working with Andriod and IOS even not working in firefox too.
Tried to implement using (https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC) too but we have different js for firefox and chrome and its not working with IOS and Andriod.

If anybody know a solution which one work for chrome, firefox, andriod and IOS than please reply.
Waiting for the response, in the mean time trying my own to find out some solutions.

Comment: getUserMedia is not supported by some mobile browsers yet... check here for a full table: http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

Comment: You will unfortunately have to use an alternative approach (like native apps) to get AV content off iOS & Android. (Although it looks like android is supporting the spec somewhat).